# Can not email PDF from QLPreviewController

Tags: ios, pdf, ios8, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, qlpreviewcontroller

I'm successfully loading a PDF file downloaded from the web into QLPreviewController. When I tap the "Share" button and then tap the Mail icon to email the PDF, the mail composer window shows momentarily (without the PDF), then dismisses on it's own. Then, on my Mac, a "Problem Reporter" window shows up with the following details:

> Process:               MailCompositionService [68119] Path:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/Applications/MailCompositionService.app/MailCompositionService
>   Identifier:            MailCompositionService Version:
>   1.0 (1.0) Code Type:             X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:        launchd_sim [67687] Responsible:           launchd_sim [67687] User
>   ID:               501
>
> Date/Time:             2014-12-10 16:03:36.006 -0600 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.10.1 (14B25) Report Version:        11 Anonymous UUID:
>   027528DA-56B6-94EF-4660-573FD98B58EC
>
> Sleep/Wake UUID:       BC8F4A6B-CCAC-4E18-9A39-A6F533C76D2E
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 1700000 seconds Time Since Wake:       1700000
>   seconds
>
> Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
>
> Application Specific Information:
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSRegularExpression
>   enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:]: nil argument'
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException abort() called

This is also printed in the Xcode log:

> 2014-12-10 16:03:36.862 Q-Scribe[67995:17783435]
>   viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error
>   Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 3.)"
>   UserInfo=0x7be9b8c0 {Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
>   2014-12-10 16:03:45.788 Q-Scribe[67995:17878367]
>    timed out waiting for
>   fence barrier from com.apple.MailCompositionService

One of Apple's mail libraries is obviously crashing. All answers to similar questions suggested things that assumed a reference to the MFMailComposeViewController, but since I'm in QuickLook, I don't have access to it.

This is occurring on the iOS 8 iPad simulator.

How can I email my PDF from QLPreviewController?

Comment: You should probably file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com (with sample code).

Comment: I'm having the same problem in the iOS 8 iPhone simulator. I'm not trying to send a PDF, just text though.